# Proper encode data before sending to url with urlencode

Tags: php, ajax, url, urlencode

I was sending data to URL and it gives me this error

> failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported in

my code:

```
<?php 
$pickup_time= '2016-8-20 11:11';
$city = 'Islamabad';

$pickup_address= 'aaa';
$dropoff_address = 'bbb';
$pickup_area= 'Street 1, F-8, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan';
$drop_area= 'Karachi, Sindh, Pakistan';
$multi_areas = 'Lake View Park, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan';
$description = 'nill';

$booking_fare = '30590';
$deadmile_distance = 'nill';
$actual_distance = '1519';
$payment_method = '1';

$pickup_area = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $pickup_area);// remove commas from string
$drop_area = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $drop_area);// remove commas from string
$multi_areas = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $multi_areas);// remove commas from string


$jsonData = file_get_contents("https://daewoocab-test.herokuapp.com/api/v1/customer/923331524145/booking/new?token=6ab676ddd7bf00101408ea3a27fdbb8ad22e9dcdf2faafdcd2ef0efc1509d463&booking[pickup_time]=$pickup_time&booking[city]=$city&booking[pickup_address]=$pickup_address&booking[drop_address]=$dropoff_address&booking[pickup_area]=$pickup_area&booking[drop_area]=$drop_area&booking[multi_areas]=($multi_areas)&booking[description]=$description&booking[booking_fare]=$booking_fare&booking[deadmile_distance]=$deadmile_distance&booking[actual_distance]=$actual_distance&booking[payment_method]=$payment_method");
$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $json['bookings']['id'];
?>
```

But after searching, I used urlencode with my strings to remove the spaces and now my code is :

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("https://daewoocab-test.herokuapp.com/api/v1/customer/923331524145/booking/new?token=6ab676ddd7bf00101408ea3a27fdbb8ad22e9dcdf2faafdcd2ef0efc1509d463&booking[pickup_time]=" . urlencode($pickup_time)"&booking[city]=$city&booking[pickup_address]=$pickup_address&booking[drop_address]=$dropoff_address&booking[pickup_area]=". urlencode($pickup_area)"&booking[drop_area]=". urlencode($drop_area)"&booking[multi_areas]=(" . urlencode($multi_areas)")&booking[description]=$description&booking[booking_fare]=$booking_fare&booking[deadmile_distance]=$deadmile_distance&booking[actual_distance]=$actual_distance&booking[payment_method]=$payment_method
```

Still it gives me the syntax error, I have checked it like 100 times but not found any syntax error. Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: When you put the URL in `file_get_contents()` method, in a browser? Do you get a response? Just try punching that url in the address bar to confirm if its a syntax error as far as URL generation or encoding is concerned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480720/http-1-1-505-http-version-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("https://daewoocab-test.herokuapp.com/api/v1/customer/923331524145/booking/new?token=6ab676ddd7bf00101408ea3a27fdbb8ad22e9dcdf2faafdcd2ef0efc1509d463&booking[pickup_time]=" . urlencode($pickup_time)."&booking[city]=$city&booking[pickup_address]=$pickup_address&booking[drop_address]=$dropoff_address&booking[pickup_area]=". urlencode($pickup_area)."&booking[drop_area]=". urlencode($drop_area)."&booking[multi_areas]=(" . urlencode($multi_areas).")&booking[description]=$description&booking[booking_fare]=$booking_fare&booking[deadmile_distance]=$deadmile_distance&booking[actual_distance]=$actual_distance&booking[payment_method]=$payment_method");
```

But this is not the proper way. You should break them variables and then concatenate them with each other.